# Start a ConEmu tab with a delay

Tags: conemu

I'm trying to set up a task in ConEmu to start a Mongo DB server, wait few seconds and start a new ConEmu tab with a Mongo client.

My current ConEmu configuration looks like this:

```
> cmd /k C:\bin\MongoDb2.6\bin\client-delay.bat
cmd /k C:\bin\MongoDb2.6\bin\mongo-start.bat -cur_console:s25H
```

The client-delay.bat script is using the timeout.exe command to create delay.

**Is there a way to add a delay in ConEmu directly instead of using timeout command?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is general tab creation timeout setting, but it affects **all** possible tasks. Almost useless in your case and you'll lose ability to cancel waiting. Option was created for debug purposes.

Why do not to use `timeout` in the task itself?

```
> cmd /k C:\bin\MongoDb2.6\bin\client-delay.bat
cmd /k timeout 10 & C:\bin\MongoDb2.6\bin\mongo-start.bat -cur_console:s25H
```